# What is the memory footprint of a descriptor heap?

Tags: directx, directx-12

Let say I want to create a descriptor heap of given type and capacity:

```
void CreateHeap(ID3D12DescriptorHeap** destBuffer, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE descType, UINT capacity)
{
    D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC heapDesc = {};
    heapDesc.NumDescriptors = capacity;
    heapDesc.Type = descType;

    if (descType == D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV)
        heapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE;
    else
        heapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE;

    const HRESULT hr = D3D12Device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&heapDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(destBuffer));
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    (*destBuffer)->SetName(L"My Descriptor Heap");

    const UINT descriptorSize = D3D12Device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(descType);
    std::cout << " Descriptor handle increment size:" << descriptorSize << std::endl;
}
```

The value returned by GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize is **152** which seems to be too huge.
**What is the memory footprint of a descriptor heap?**
I checked on PIX but the information is not there:

[image]

Comment: I imagine it depends of `D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE` and your machine. On mine, 32 for RTV,  CBV_SRV_UAV, SAMPLER, 8 for DSV

Comment: Thanks for helping. It is 32 bits or bytes?

Comment: Bytes. Whatever `GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize` returns. DirectX always works with bytes I believe

Comment: I bet you're running on AMD? AMD gives me 152 while NVIDIA gives me 32. It's called "increment size", I don't think it really related with a descriptor memory, it's just an opaque value. Official doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/creating-descriptor-heaps#descriptor-handles clearly states *"must never hardcode descriptor handle increment sizes, and should always query them for a given device instance [...] must also not use the increment sizes and handles to do their own examination or manipulation of descriptor heap data, as the results [...] are undefined"*

Comment: awesome :) Thank you!